# How can these two arguments relate?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers, primitive-roots

I found the excerpt here that said the second involves the p-adic analog of the above. How can these two statement related?

- The transcendence of $2^{\sqrt2}$ and $e^\pi$: Gelfand's proof. (Assuming some basic complex analysis).
- Nathanson's problem: show that $3^n\nmid5^n-2$ for $n>1$. (This involves the $p$-adic analogue of the above topic.)

I showed the second argument by the following, but try to find a way of the first prove and I don't know how they related,

Firstly, we assume that there exist an $n>1$ satisfying $3^n|(5^n-2)$. We have that $2,5$ are the primitive root modulo $3^n$. Thus,
$$\left\{2^1,2^2,\dots , 2^{\varphi{(3^n)}}\right\}=\left\{5^1,5^2,\dots , 5^{\varphi(3^n)}\right\}.$$
Hence, we can choose $b\in[1,2\cdot 3^{n-1}]\cap\mathbb Z$ so that $2^n\equiv 5^b\pmod{3^n}$. Therefore, by the premise $5^n\equiv 2\pmod{3^n}$,
$$5^{n^2}\equiv 2^n\equiv 5^b\pmod{3^n}\Longrightarrow 5^{|b-n^2|}\equiv 1\pmod {3^n}.$$
Since $5$ is a primitive root we have that $$\varphi(3^n)=2\cdot 3^{n-1}\Big||b-n^2|\Longrightarrow 2\cdot 3^{n-1}\le b-n^2<2\cdot 3^{n-1}.$$
As $|b-n^2|=b-n^2$ otherwise $n^2-b$ is still far less than $2\cdot 3^{n-1}.$ I hope it is valid and thank you in advance for my question.

---

The above is invalid as $b=n^2.$ I give a proof here,

Let $\alpha_i$ be the number such that $5^{\alpha_i}\equiv 2\pmod{3^i}$. We will show that $\alpha_i>i$ for all $i>1$. Notice that we have the proof that $\alpha_i\le\alpha_{i+1}$.

We assume otherwise that $\alpha_i>\alpha_{i+1}$ for some $i$. We have $$5^{\alpha_{i+1}}\equiv 2\pmod{3^{i+1}}\Longrightarrow 5^{\alpha_{i+1}}\equiv 2\equiv 5^{\alpha_i}\pmod{3^{i}}\Longrightarrow 5^{\alpha_i-\alpha_{i+1}}\equiv 1\pmod{3^{i}}.$$
Which means that $\varphi(3^i)\le \alpha_{i}-\alpha_{i+1}<\varphi(3^i)$, a contradiction.

By the definition of $\alpha_i$ we have that it must be in the form $6k+5$ for $i>1$ since $5^{\alpha_i}\equiv 2\pmod 9$ and $\alpha_i$ is not in the form $6k+3$ otherwise $5^{\alpha_i}\equiv 5^{6k+3}\equiv 8\not\equiv 2\pmod 9$. The same argument goes for $\alpha_i=6k+1$ that $5^{\alpha_i}\equiv 5\not\equiv 2\pmod 9$.

The problem is in the case $\alpha_i=\alpha_{i+1}$. Consider the set $$\left\{5^0,5^1,5^2,\dots,5^{\varphi(3^i)-1}\right\}.$$
Let $x$ be a smallest number that $5^x>3^i$. If $\alpha_i\le i$ then $5^{\alpha_i}=3^i+2$ or $5^{\alpha_i}=3^{i+1}+2$ since $5^{\alpha-1}<3^i\Longrightarrow 5^\alpha<5\cdot 3^i$.

Either case is impossible since if we assume $2=5^\alpha-3^\beta$ with $\alpha=6k+5$, as $\beta$ is odd otherwise $0\equiv 3^\beta+2\equiv (-2)^\beta+2\equiv 2^\beta+2 \pmod {5}\Longrightarrow 2^{\beta-3}\equiv 1\pmod 5$, which means that $4|(\beta-3)$ and it is impossible, then we have that
$$2\equiv 5^{6k+5}-3^{\beta}\equiv 0,4,5 \pmod{7}$$
a contradiction occurs. Thus, $\alpha_i>i$ for any $i$ as desired. Hence, $3^n|(5^n-2)$ only when $n=1$.

Comment: Please don’t use images for text. They are not searchable (either within the site or by websearchers) making it difficult for future users to find the post; they don’t adjust to displays, so they may show badly for some (it is extremely small in my display, for instance); and screen readers cannot process them, making your post inaccessible for people who use them. This is a very small amount of text, you can type it in.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you I updated it as a quote.